# semantic ui form validation in rails (error messages invisible/not showing)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, semantic-ui

I am using Semantic UI as the CSS framework for a Rails project.  I am trying to get form validations to work on forms created using the `form_tag` helper.  Everything seems to be working, except the error messages are not being shown. If you check the HTML, you can see that `<li>` elements containing the error messages are added to the DOM by Semantic UI, they are just not visible. Everything works fine if I do the same thing on a regular HTML form rather than a form generated by the `form_tag` helper.  It's as though Rails' `form_tag` helper throws off the selectors that Semantic UI uses to select the `<div>` and show the errors.

Here is the form:

Note: The form is nested inside the `<div class="ui form">` so that the styling works properly. This may be part of the problem.

```
<div class="ui form">
  <%= form_tag review_path, method: :put, class: "review-form" do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, current_user.id %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :id, skatepark.id %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= text_area_tag :review, nil, placeholder: 'Write review here...' %>
    </div>
    <%= submit_tag 'Review', class: "ui button" %>

    <div class="ui error message"></div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
$('.review-form').form({
  fields: {
    review: {
      identifier  : 'review',
      rules: [
        {
          type   : 'empty',
          prompt : 'Please enter a value'
        }
      ]
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `ui form` classes from the `div` tag down to the `form` tag. It appears that the `.form()` plugin has its quirks if this isn't done.

**Result:**

```
<div>
  <%= form_tag review_path, method: :put, class: "ui form review-form" do |f| %>
    <!-- rest of code -->
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**Snippet:**

```js
$(function() {
  $('.review-form').form({
    fields: {
      review: {
        identifier: 'review',
        rules: [{
          type: 'empty',
          prompt: 'Please enter a value'
        }]
      },
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link href="//oss.maxcdn.com/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="ui container">
  <div class="ui two columns grid">
    <div class="column">
      <h3 class="ui header">Classes on DIV</h3>
      <div class="ui form">
        <form class="review-form">
          <div class="field">
            <textarea id="review" rows="2" placeholder="Write review here"></textarea>
          </div>
          <button class="ui button">Submit</button>
          <div class="ui error message"></div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h3 class="ui header">Classes on FORM</h3>
      <div>
        <form class="ui form review-form">
          <div class="field">
            <textarea id="review" rows="2" placeholder="Write review here"></textarea>
          </div>
          <button class="ui button">Submit</button>
          <div class="ui error message"></div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```